# Connecting second postgresql database from my nodejs application

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

My api server uses 2 databases on heroku first one the regular process.env.DATABASE_URL the other one process.env.HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN_URL

I can connect both databases via pgAdmin also my aplication can reach both local databases on my machine..

if I try to reach them at heroku server postgres.. if I use my local server it complaints about the second db doesn't support SSL..

if I upload the project on heroku first one connects as local and second one gives this error

```
2020-12-23T10:49:36.771129+00:00 app[web.1]: Api Server is running
2020-12-23T10:49:36.775516+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2020-12-23T10:49:36.775516+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]         (net.js:1144:16) {
2020-12-23T10:49:36.775517+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2020-12-23T10:49:36.775517+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2020-12-23T10:49:36.775517+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2020-12-23T10:49:36.775517+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2020-12-23T10:49:36.775518+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
2020-12-23T10:49:36.775518+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-12-23T10:49:36.803425+00:00 app[web.1]: Main Connected at Wed Dec 23 2020 10:49:36 GMT+0000     (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

the second one thinks that the database is on localhost.. I printed both URL's are true but I couldn't find the problem...

Thanks..

```
const donemPool = new Pool({
   process.env.HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN_URL,
  ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }

  });

 donemPool.connect()
     .then(donemclient => {return donemclient.query('SELECT NOW() as 
 simdi')
                                         .then(donemrows => {
                                          donemclient.release();
                                          console.log('Donem 
Connected at ' + donemrows.rows[0].simdi);
                                        }).catch(error => 
 {donemclient.release();
                                           console.log(error); })
                                       } ).catch(error => 
  {console.log(error);});
```

Comment: Please show the code where you try to connect to these servers.

Comment: const donemPool = new Pool({
  process.env.HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CYAN_URL,
  ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
 
 });

Comment: I added the connection style